# How to fix glitched bounty in Solstheim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm playing the latest DLC for Skyrim, Dragonborn. I didn't commit any crime, but somehow I got a bounty on me. I've read that this may be a glitch with one of the quests I'm doing, "Cleansing the stones".

My problem is that I can't get rid of the bounty. If I travel to Solstheim's main city, Raven Rock, Captain Veleth starts attacking me, and then the rest of the guards join in. It doesn't matter if I sheathe my weapons, they keep being hostile and don't give me a chance to pay the bounty, get arrested or anything.

I've tried speaking to a guard before he becomes hostile, but it didn't solve the problem neither, as he doesn't give any dialog option.

Did anybody have this problem? How did you solve it?

As a last resource, I could go back to an older saved game, but I did a lot of progress since the last one and I wouldn't like to lose it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, finally!

It seems that I had no bounty on my head, despite the guards being hostile to me. Weird. Anyway, I punched on the face a NPC (*not* a guard!), which gave me a 40 septim bounty, and after that I was able to surrender and pay the bounty as usual.

So, if anybody else has the same issue in the future, all you need to do is give yourself a proper bounty, by attacking somebody who isn't already hostile to you. I guess stealing something, pickpocketing, lockpicking, etc, would be valid as well.

I wish I knew what triggered the bug...